# How to make the display content responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble resizing the content. When resizing the browser window the SVG image changes scale but the red dots stay in place. Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/8fdw3jh6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title></title>
   <meta name="description" content="Interaktywny poradnik szybkiego startu dla Brackets.">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="panele_solarne.css">



</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
     <svg id="PV_svg" viewBox="0 0 4793 4950" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onload="var src; if (document.documentURI) src = document.documentURI; else if (this.getSrc) src = this.getSrc(); else src = document.location.href + ''; try {parent.preload.load(src);}catch(e) {}" width="100%" height="100%"><path d="M143.515 4733.376l662.293-2452.454 531.914-558.737 318.63-500.329 616.195-442.396 476.63 71.1-108.496 252.335-341.8 84.728-107.27 225.14 41.436 127.724 81.633 21.066-34.233 273.864-487.162-71.099-23.7 508.229 650.427 279.131-226.464 861.093 200.131 56.616 134.3-176.432 334.43 84.266 13.166-685.978 180.382-38.183 21.067-408.163 324.908-470.9-24.206-100.549-297.925-29.793 44.688-534.403 572.68 88.904L3842 961.158l547.729-463.462 86.596 259.632-247.228 2349.979-549.045 64.516-200.132 667.544-2189.598 15.8-679.394 703.094z" opacity=".204" fill="#00f" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><g opacity=".522" fill="green" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="15"><path d="M183.876 4624.769h209.013l8.379-34.448h93.101l49.344-187.134 201.514-.292 31.6-129.032h100.065L937.46 4023.7l-318.631 1.316 57.933-230.414H402.897z" stroke="#000"/><path d="M2292.161 826.224h210.41l.452 24.206h124.304l-.413 26.068h87.928l-74.161 226.397-167.903.771-3.724 39.103-206.685 1.862-70.758 268.133 91.24 363.096-316.545 1.862v-37.24l-72.956-326.394 22.68-79.53-294.23.982 32.239-63.651h78.68l26.492-92.937 189.439.771 15.8-39.5-93.483 1.317 11.85-40.816h65.833l21.066-73.733h94.8l37.718-109.528 89.997 1.562 10.533-39.5 96.116-1.316z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M1621.8 1335.54l-35.349 95.844 26.068 139.652h-158.272l27.93 128.48 7.449 31.655 78.205 1.862 1.862 57.723-264.409-1.862-35.378 44.689 9.31 78.205-94.964 1.862-14.896 57.723-39.103 171.307 301.65 1.862-13.035 61.447 296.063 1.862 59.585-296.063 1.862-171.307h189.928l-72.956-326.393 22.68-79.53z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M1130.253 2142.68l-191.337 1.862-39.874 137.151-93.234-.77-47.19 180.164h89.152l-11.944 42.282-89.47-.546-76.025 313.913 599.652 1.277 148.885-612.024 13.035-61.447z" stroke="#000"/><path d="M1418.868 2205.99l-158.273 654.505 266.27-.932 9.31-27.931h310.959l126.619-463.647h-91.24l7.449-33.517-201.872-.77-22.118 87.128-20.153-.814 53.983-213.298-280.934-.727M676.76 3794.6l102.7-389.73h331.797l149.338-544.375 9.388-42.482-599.652-1.277L402.897 3794.6z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M937.459 4023.699l6.591-33.883h191.79l31.654-137.79 96.826 1.861 123.435-449.468-276.498.452H779.46l-102.7 389.73-57.932 230.414zM1191.7 3110.937H2070.58l165.102-625.092-94.8-2.633 7.9-31.6h-197.498l-104.15 380.02h-310.958l-9.31 27.931-266.27.932z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M2044.51 3170.522l-69.214 306.915-242.516 1.543-94.192 320.908-3.724 37.241-344.156-.639 97.916-379.216h101.002l9.31-52.136-111.181-.72-276.498.453 63.685-238.074z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M1983.835 3434.93l194.742 1.862-5.586 33.517 93.873 1.09-36.695 139.879-101.867.545-11.172 48.413 100.87-.771-33.837 106.907 8.38 29.792-4.27 38.624-553.41 2.341 3.725-37.24 94.192-320.91 242.516-1.542z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M4236.122 684.71l202.962 1.861 11.172 46.55 15.827 29.793-81.62 751.24-587.229-2.634 52.666-458.196 89.533-2.633 18.433-165.899 100.066 2.634 2.633-79h102.7v-47.4l-13.167-39.499 86.899-5.267z" stroke="#0b1728" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M3805.993 1219.112l-392.889 1.862 5.586-40.964h-201.099l-9.31 76.343 16.758-1.862-35.379 335.166h-14.896v37.24l297.925-1.862-44.688 409.647h297.925zM3739.301 2072.416l581.962 2.633 63.2-560.895-587.229-2.634-18.433 186.965 93.482-1.316-3.95 43.45h-97.432zM3725.926 2034.682L3691.9 2354.18l-586.137 2.5 9.443-136.8 85.356-2.632 36.547-180.156zM3739.301 2072.416l-14.483 126.398h98.75l-7.9 60.567h-98.75l-10.533 93.482 583.278 1.317 31.6-279.131zM3105.764 2356.68l-32.69 324.03 581.51-.506 37.318-326.024z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M3706.385 2352.863l-20.22 180.844h101.208l-5.586 39.102-96.826 1.862-13.034 126.619h316.545l1.862-18.62 266.958-.098 32.371-328.392z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M4257.292 2682.572l-38.728 411.568-292.298-1.317-5.266 22.384-306.781 2.633 32.916-223.832h102.7l2.633-42.133h-100.066l19.525-150.585h316.545l1.862-18.62zM3654.583 2680.204l-5.932 42.499-303.03 1.457 8.558-44.108z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M3073.073 2680.71l-10.533 97.433-107.194 653.832 596.538-.452 22.158-126.266-102.248-.452 6.81-42.133h102.699l67.348-539.97-303.03 1.458 8.558-44.108z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path d="M2955.346 3431.975l5.285-32.423h-290.477l-70.984 383.578-10.626.28-7.241 38.182 303.582-.658 14.39-55.3 90.85-.545-15.8 54.528h492.429l85.13-388.094zM2323.897 3493.087l-60.567 323.897h163.266l-39.5-323.897zM2427.912 3448.32l-7.9 23.7 2.634 102.7 32.916 243.58h106.65l2.633-32.916 67.149-337.064z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/></g></svg>
     <div class="stationlocationcontainer">
           <svg width="60" height="60" class="stationlocation">
             <rect class="station" rx="50%" ry="50%" x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5"></rect>
           </svg>
           <svg width="60" height="60" class="stationlocation">
             <rect class="station" rx="50%" ry="50%" x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5"></rect>
           </svg>
           <svg width="60" height="60" class="stationlocation">
             <rect class="station"rx="50%" ry="50%" x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5"></rect>
           </svg>
           <svg width="60" height="60" class="stationlocation">
             <rect class="station"rx="50%" ry="50%" x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5"></rect>
           </svg>
     </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: coordonates are pixels, turn them into % so the size matters.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to make your width max-content and your margin 0px auto in your css

```
width:max-content;
margin: 0px auto;
```

please take a look at my answer for this post over here. And search for

```
a good convention
```

It will take you to the post. Or search my name. :)

[Full screen width header in html/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200508/full-screen-width-header-in-html-css/58201098#58201098)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason why the dots aren't scaling with the screen is because their position is absolute and statically based on pixels.

```
.stationlocation:nth-child(1){
    position:absolute;
    top:140px;
    left:575px;
}
```

You may want to consider using CSS Grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/. Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the jsfiddle with working code https://jsfiddle.net/gotn9mqx/

Wrap all the SVG's in a div and add position relative to it and then you can give absolute positioning to the inner elements and can use positioning adjustments (top,left etc) in percentages to place the elements in required position. Below is the working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Interaktywny poradnik szybkiego startu dla Brackets.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="panele_solarne.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="svg-wrap">
        <svg id="PV_svg" viewBox="0 0 4793 4950" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onload="var src; if (document.documentURI) src = document.documentURI; else if (this.getSrc) src = this.getSrc(); else src = document.location.href + ''; try {parent.preload.load(src);}catch(e) {}" width="100%" height="100%">
          <path d="M143.515 4733.376l662.293-2452.454 531.914-558.737 318.63-500.329 616.195-442.396 476.63 71.1-108.496 252.335-341.8 84.728-107.27 225.14 41.436 127.724 81.633 21.066-34.233 273.864-487.162-71.099-23.7 508.229 650.427 279.131-226.464 861.093 200.131 56.616 134.3-176.432 334.43 84.266 13.166-685.978 180.382-38.183 21.067-408.163 324.908-470.9-24.206-100.549-297.925-29.793 44.688-534.403 572.68 88.904L3842 961.158l547.729-463.462 86.596 259.632-247.228 2349.979-549.045 64.516-200.132 667.544-2189.598 15.8-679.394 703.094z" opacity=".204" fill="#00f" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
          <g opacity=".522" fill="green" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="15">
            <path d="M183.876 4624.769h209.013l8.379-34.448h93.101l49.344-187.134 201.514-.292 31.6-129.032h100.065L937.46 4023.7l-318.631 1.316 57.933-230.414H402.897z" stroke="#000" />
            <path d="M2292.161 826.224h210.41l.452 24.206h124.304l-.413 26.068h87.928l-74.161 226.397-167.903.771-3.724 39.103-206.685 1.862-70.758 268.133 91.24 363.096-316.545 1.862v-37.24l-72.956-326.394 22.68-79.53-294.23.982 32.239-63.651h78.68l26.492-92.937 189.439.771 15.8-39.5-93.483 1.317 11.85-40.816h65.833l21.066-73.733h94.8l37.718-109.528 89.997 1.562 10.533-39.5 96.116-1.316z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M1621.8 1335.54l-35.349 95.844 26.068 139.652h-158.272l27.93 128.48 7.449 31.655 78.205 1.862 1.862 57.723-264.409-1.862-35.378 44.689 9.31 78.205-94.964 1.862-14.896 57.723-39.103 171.307 301.65 1.862-13.035 61.447 296.063 1.862 59.585-296.063 1.862-171.307h189.928l-72.956-326.393 22.68-79.53z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M1130.253 2142.68l-191.337 1.862-39.874 137.151-93.234-.77-47.19 180.164h89.152l-11.944 42.282-89.47-.546-76.025 313.913 599.652 1.277 148.885-612.024 13.035-61.447z" stroke="#000" />
            <path d="M1418.868 2205.99l-158.273 654.505 266.27-.932 9.31-27.931h310.959l126.619-463.647h-91.24l7.449-33.517-201.872-.77-22.118 87.128-20.153-.814 53.983-213.298-280.934-.727M676.76 3794.6l102.7-389.73h331.797l149.338-544.375 9.388-42.482-599.652-1.277L402.897 3794.6z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M937.459 4023.699l6.591-33.883h191.79l31.654-137.79 96.826 1.861 123.435-449.468-276.498.452H779.46l-102.7 389.73-57.932 230.414zM1191.7 3110.937H2070.58l165.102-625.092-94.8-2.633 7.9-31.6h-197.498l-104.15 380.02h-310.958l-9.31 27.931-266.27.932z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M2044.51 3170.522l-69.214 306.915-242.516 1.543-94.192 320.908-3.724 37.241-344.156-.639 97.916-379.216h101.002l9.31-52.136-111.181-.72-276.498.453 63.685-238.074z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M1983.835 3434.93l194.742 1.862-5.586 33.517 93.873 1.09-36.695 139.879-101.867.545-11.172 48.413 100.87-.771-33.837 106.907 8.38 29.792-4.27 38.624-553.41 2.341 3.725-37.24 94.192-320.91 242.516-1.542z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M4236.122 684.71l202.962 1.861 11.172 46.55 15.827 29.793-81.62 751.24-587.229-2.634 52.666-458.196 89.533-2.633 18.433-165.899 100.066 2.634 2.633-79h102.7v-47.4l-13.167-39.499 86.899-5.267z" stroke="#0b1728" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M3805.993 1219.112l-392.889 1.862 5.586-40.964h-201.099l-9.31 76.343 16.758-1.862-35.379 335.166h-14.896v37.24l297.925-1.862-44.688 409.647h297.925zM3739.301 2072.416l581.962 2.633 63.2-560.895-587.229-2.634-18.433 186.965 93.482-1.316-3.95 43.45h-97.432zM3725.926 2034.682L3691.9 2354.18l-586.137 2.5 9.443-136.8 85.356-2.632 36.547-180.156zM3739.301 2072.416l-14.483 126.398h98.75l-7.9 60.567h-98.75l-10.533 93.482 583.278 1.317 31.6-279.131zM3105.764 2356.68l-32.69 324.03 581.51-.506 37.318-326.024z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M3706.385 2352.863l-20.22 180.844h101.208l-5.586 39.102-96.826 1.862-13.034 126.619h316.545l1.862-18.62 266.958-.098 32.371-328.392z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M4257.292 2682.572l-38.728 411.568-292.298-1.317-5.266 22.384-306.781 2.633 32.916-223.832h102.7l2.633-42.133h-100.066l19.525-150.585h316.545l1.862-18.62zM3654.583 2680.204l-5.932 42.499-303.03 1.457 8.558-44.108z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M3073.073 2680.71l-10.533 97.433-107.194 653.832 596.538-.452 22.158-126.266-102.248-.452 6.81-42.133h102.699l67.348-539.97-303.03 1.458 8.558-44.108z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M2955.346 3431.975l5.285-32.423h-290.477l-70.984 383.578-10.626.28-7.241 38.182 303.582-.658 14.39-55.3 90.85-.545-15.8 54.528h492.429l85.13-388.094zM2323.897 3493.087l-60.567 323.897h163.266l-39.5-323.897zM2427.912 3448.32l-7.9 23.7 2.634 102.7 32.916 243.58h106.65l2.633-32.916 67.149-337.064z" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
          </g>
        </svg>
        <div class="stationlocationcontainer">
          <svg width="60" height="60" class="stationlocation">
            <rect class="station" rx="50%" ry="50%" x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5"></rect>
          </svg>
          <svg width="60" height="60" class="stationlocation">
            <rect class="station" rx="50%" ry="50%" x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5"></rect>
          </svg>
          <svg width="60" height="60" class="stationlocation">
            <rect class="station" rx="50%" ry="50%" x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5"></rect>
          </svg>
          <svg width="60" height="60" class="stationlocation">
            <rect class="station" rx="50%" ry="50%" x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5"></rect>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Below is the css code:

```
html,
body {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.station {
  stroke-width: 6;
  stroke: red;
  fill: red;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.stationlocationcontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%
}

.stationlocation:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 82%;
}

.stationlocation:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  left: 70%;
}

.stationlocation:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 70%;
}

.stationlocation:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 67%;
  left: 54%;
}

#PV_svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.svg-wrap {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
```